# does this series converge? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\left( \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n-1} \right)^\alpha} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> show the the following series converge\diverge
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\left( \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n-1} \right)^\alpha} $

all the test i tried failed (root test, ratio test,direct comparison)

please dont use integrals as this is out of the scope for me right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** rationalize:

$$\left( \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n-1} \right)^\alpha = \left( \frac{2}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1})^2+ \sqrt[3]{n-1}\sqrt[3]{n+1}+ (\sqrt[3]{n-1})^2} \right)^\alpha$$

Compare with $$\sum\frac{1}{n^{\frac{2\alpha}{3}}}$$

Comment: could you explain the algebra you did in the first step?

Comment: @user1333057 It is rationalization for cubic roots. $$\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}=\left( \sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b} \right) \frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}\\=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}$$ The top is just the formula $$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$$ with $x=\sqrt[3]{a}, y=\sqrt[3]{b}$

Comment: wow, i would have never have guessed that, what made you try thas route?

Comment: @guynaa It is a standard tool, the problem is that in Calculus we teach square root rationalization, but the same ideas work for higher roots. Is just that the expression by which you rationalize is  more complicated.

Comment: The basic idea is that $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+..+y^{n-2})$$ Now if you set $x=\sqrt[n]{a}, y=\sqrt[n]{b}$ you see that multiplying $\sqrt[n]{a}-\sqrt[n]{b}$ by whatever what you get in the bracket you get $a-b$... This is the idea of rationalization...

Comment: one more thing..., i dont understand how can you simplify the expession to be $\sum\frac{1}{n^{\frac{2\alpha}{3}}}$, the denominator is not in the $(x-y)^2$ formula

Comment: @guynaa You cannot simplify to that. But you can use the Limit Comparison Test to compare what you get to the simpler limit ;)

Comment: @N.S. from comparsion test there are 3 cases: $\alpha < 0 , \ 0< \alpha < \frac32 , \ \alpha > \frac 32 $. Each one behaves differently.

Comment: @GinKin True, don't forget about the equality $\alpha \leq 0, 0 < \alpha \leq \frac{3}{2}$. Also when one covers the $p$ series, often the cases $p \leq 0$ and $0 < p \leq 1$ are studied as a single case $p \leq 1$.

Comment: Super and yeah I just forgot the tex for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ratio test is inconclusive, but using [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) we can see that the series converges when $\alpha>\frac{3}{2}$.